# Get string without square brackets

Tags: java, json

I have json like this

```
{"First":["Already exists"],"Second":["Already exists"]}
```

Currently I am doing like

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(myJson);
String first = jObject.getString("First")
```

But I am getting result like this

```
first = ["Already exists"]
```

But I want string without square brackets or `""`

Comment: use JSONArray instead.

Comment: Actually, you are getting `first = "[\"Already exists\"]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using JSONArray :

```
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONObject(myJson).getJSONArray("First");
    String first = jArray.getString(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json message with key 'first' is Array. So use should treat as Array.

```
String string = "{'First':['Already exists'],'Second':['Already exists']}";
    JSONObject jObject;
    try
    {
        jObject = new JSONObject(string);
        Object myJson = jObject.get("First");
        if(myJson instanceof JSONArray)
        {
            JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("First");
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println("val : "+jArray.getString(i));
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @m.qadhavi i was able to figure out how it works

```
 //This was my temporary solution
 //get no. of garage
 properties.setPropertyFeaturesGarage(jsonObject
.getJSONObject("extras")
.getString("property_garages")
.replaceAll("[\"]", "")
.replace('[',' ')
.replace(']',' '));
```

But after going through @m.qadhavi explanation i corrected my code

```
 //get land size
 properties.setPropertyFeaturesLandSize(jsonObject
.getJSONObject("extras")
.getJSONArray("property_size")
.getString(0));
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score -1):

Try to get Substring like e.g.

```
String first = jObject.getString("First")
String subFirst = first.substring(2,first.length()-2);
```

Comment: While this would "work", it doesn't seem like the correct approach